# How to configure a generic component with FluentNHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, components

Here is the component for which I want to configure mapping

```
public class Range<T> : ValueObject
{
    public virtual T Start {get; set;}
    public virtual T Finish {get; set;}
}
```

In my domain I have many entities which have properties like Range < DateTime>, Range < int > ... for a particular class with property x we configure the component this way:

```
 persistenceModel.FindMapping<Customer>()  
     .Component<Address>            (  
                 x => x.CustomerAddress,  
                 m =>  
                 {  
                     m.Map(x => x.Street).WithLengthOf(100);  
                     m.Map(x => x.PostalCode).WithLengthOf(6);  
                     m.Map(x => x.Town).WithLengthOf(30);  
                     m.Map(x => x.Country).WithLengthOf(50);  
                 });
```

How looks the convention for whole domain as generic T ?
Do I miss something. Is not possible with FluentNhibernate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `FindMapping` for that purpose. Being able to alter the mappings through that method is an oversight, and should definitely not be relied upon. That method is for *inspecting* the persistence model, not altering it. If you're using automapping, you should look into [overrides](https://1map.com/fluentnhibernateorg#Altering_entities).

---

I believe your problem could be solved with an `ICompositeUserType` implementation; there are several resources available online on how to implement these, specifically a [generic composite user type implementation](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127201844/http://geekswithblogs.net/opiesblog/archive/2006/08/13/87880.aspx). You'd just map your range property as normal, but supply the user type to it using `CustomType`.

```
Map(x => x.Range)
  .CustomType<RangeUserType>();
```

You could also do it with the newly introduced `ComponentMap` functionality, but it doesn't support mapping *open* generic types without the use of base-classes.

Something like this would probably work:

```
public abstract class RangeMap<T> : ComponentMap<T>
{
  protected RangeMap()
  {
    Map(x => x.Start);
    Map(x => x.Finish):
  }
}

public class IntRangeMap : RangeMap<int>
{}

public class DateRangeMap : RangeMap<DateTime>
{}
```

Admittedly, it's not ideal.